# request for synonym to new tag [worldend]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I just made the (possibly not yet approved) tag [worldend] for the series *WorldEnd: What Are You Doing at the End of the World? Will You Save Us?* (aka *Shūmatsu Nani Shitemasu ka? Isogashii Desu ka? Sukutte Moratte Ii Desu ka?*). Even though it is commonly referred to as **SukaSuka**, I chose the main name based on my understanding that English is the preferred language for tags.

However, due to its prevalence, I request someone add the synonym **[sukasuka]**.

Comment: Added [sukasuka] and a couple other title fragments as synonyms.